# How to use OAuth on android to pull data into our server(not to phone)?

Tags: android, facebook, oauth-2.0

I have 3 entities:

1.Android Phone

2.Local Server

3.Fb Server

I want user to login from his phone on to FB , but once authenticated , I want to be able to pull data into local server from FB(no data on to phone).

What is the best way to do this ?.
Is there a way to do this using oAuth ?

Comment: My understanding is that the OAuth protocol works by bouncing the user from web page to web page. You could obviously do this from a browser launched from your app, but I don't know if you can do it directly from your app.  I'd be interested to see if anybody actually has an answer for this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.From my understanding I can "directly" pull into the phone using Oauth on my App.But here I am trying to use App only for login and getting the Secret Key.The final data has to be pulled in to a server(which can not directly talk to user).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is certainly no problem. Just implement the [server-side authentication flow](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/server-side/) on your web server. Instead of placing a login button on a website where you redirect the user to the Facebook dialog, you open the browser on the smartphone (or embedd a Webview) with that URI. The `redirect_uri` then points to your web server callback, where you receive the authorization code. Then you exchange that code for an access token by calling Facebook from your server and you're done.

On the phone, point the browser to:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
    &redirect_uri=https://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_CALLBACK
    &scope=COMMA_SEPARATED_LIST_OF_PERMISSION_NAMES
    &state=SOME_ARBITRARY_BUT_UNIQUE_STRING
```

After handling the callback, issue a request from your server to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
    client_id=YOUR_APP_ID
    &redirect_uri=https://YOUR_SERVER/YOUR_CALLBACK
    &client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET
    &code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE_YOU_RECEIVED
```